# Centroids are not centered at clusters

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm trying to plot the centroids and clusters of my k-means analysis, using the following code:

```
matrix_reduced = TruncatedSVD(n_components = num_k).fit_transform(matrix)

matrix_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=30,verbose=2, n_iter =500).fit_transform(matrix_reduced)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
centroids_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(order_centroids)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)


ax1.scatter(matrix_embedded[:,0], matrix_embedded[:,1],marker='x',c = kmeans.labels_)
ax1.scatter(centroids_embedded[:,0], centroids_embedded[:,1],marker='o',c = 'red')

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the centroids are not centered at the different clusters:

[image]

**Question:** Does anyone know what could cause this? I have no idea what's going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running more iterations? The random centroids may need more than 500 iterations to settle. Also, I can't understand your code; you are training TSNE and then plotting centroid from K-MEANS?  These are two different things; aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

In general, when creating any manifold you need to provide all the points you want to represent on it (as the final representation usually depends and all the points in your data).

In the example, you are creating **two** different manifolds:

```
matrix_reduced = TruncatedSVD(n_components = num_k).fit_transform(matrix)

# first manifold
matrix_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=30,verbose=2, n_iter =500).fit_transform(matrix_reduced)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
# second manifold
centroids_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(order_centroids)
```

This means that the representations created are independent (and that's why you don't see them centered - they are, in fact, on a different space).

The way of fixing this is to simply join both `matrix_reduced` and `order_centroids` into a single dataset, and apply TSNE **only once**. That should show the result you are expecting.

Also, note that if you are using k-means on the original matrix (instead of on `matrix_reduced`) then the result will still be incorrect - you need to apply the same transformations to both your centroids and the data that k-means saw originally.

So in summary (and assuming you want to use `TruncatedSVD` before the clustering), it would work as follows:

1. Read the dataset
2. Apply `TruncatedSVD` to transform the whole dataset at one.
3. Use k-means on the transformed dataset to get *k* centroids
4. Get the centroids and concatenate them at the end of your dataset (as if they were additional examples)
5. Apply `TSNE` to the whole dataset.
6. (optional) Draw the first N-*k* points, as usual.
7. (optional) Draw the last *k* points (your transformed centroids) in a different color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you be a bit more elaborate on how I should do this?

Comment: Sure! I have extended my answer

Comment: I seem to be doing something else wrong as well. If I try to concatenate the two lists I get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2275,10) (10,4895)`.

Comment: @cardelling Furthermore, [http://intelligentonlinetools.com/blog/2016/06/05/using-python-for-mining-data-from-twitter-visualization-and-other-enchancements/][1] seems to do it like I'm trying to do it